# Determining whether a set is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, connectedness

> Define for a field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{F}^\omega := \{(x_n)_{n\geq 1} : x_i \in \mathbb{F}\,\forall i\}.$ Let $x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}, y=(y_n)_{n\geq 1} \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$. Define the $\infty$-norm or sup norm to be $d_\infty(x,y) := ||x-y||_\infty = \sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|x_i-y_i|.$ Define $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C}) := \{x=(x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^\omega : ||x||_\infty < \infty\}.$ Determine whether the set
> $A := \{a \in \ell_\infty(\mathbb{C}) : |a_k| = 1\,\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is connected (in the space $(\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C}), d_\infty)$).

I tried several times to show that this set is connected, but I was unsuccessful each time. For instance, I thought of using the fact that a connected subset of a metric space has no nontrivial proper closed and open sets. I also thought of defining a path between any two points of $A$ but because it would map an element of $[0,1]$ to an element with infinitely many entries, I wasn’t sure how to show that such a map would be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b=(b_k)_k=(e^{ib'_k})_k$ and $c=(c_k)_k=(e^{ic'_k})_k$ belong to $A$, with each $b'_k,c'_k\in [0,2\pi ).$

For $t\in [0,1]$ let $F(t)=(e^{i(1-t)b'_k+itc'_k})_k.$

We have $F:[0,1]\to A$ with $F(0)=b$ and $F(1)=c.$  We have $$ \|F(t)-F(t')\|=\sup_k|e^{i(1-t)b'_k+itc'_k}-e^{i(1-t')b'_k+it'c'_k}|=$$ $$=\sup_k|2\sin ((t-t')(c'_k-b'_k)/2)|\le$$ $$\le\sup_k|(t-t')(c'_k-b'_k)|\le 2\pi |t-t'|.$$ So $F$ is Lipschitz-continuous  with Lipschitz constant $2\pi.$ So $F$ is a path in $A$ from $b$ to $c.$ So $A$ is path-connected, so $A$ is connected.

Comment: Re: A comment by the proposer to the A by @tomasz about an equicontinuous family of functions: We only need to consider one function $F=F_{b,c}$ by itself for each pair $b,c\in A.$

Comment: can you please explain how you obtained your second equality involving supremums (i.e.$\lVert F(t)-F(t')\rVert = \cdots = \sup_{k} |2\sin \cdots|$?

Comment: For real $u,v$ we have  $e^{iu}-e^{iv}=$ $e^{i(u+v)/2}\cdot (e^{i(u-v)/2}-e^{-i(u-v)/2})=$ $e^{i(u+v)/2}\cdot 2\sin ((u-v)/2)$... So $|e^{iu}-e^{iv}|=$ $|e^{i(u+v)/2}|\cdot |2\sin ((u-v)/2)|=$ $1\cdot  |2\sin ((u-v)/2)|. $

Comment: We can also avoid some details by noting that for real $u,v$ we have $|e^{iu}-e^{iv}|=$ $=|(\cos u -\cos v)+i(\sin u-\sin v)|\le$ $ |\cos u-\cos v|+|i(\sin u-\sin v)|=$ $=|\cos u-\cos v|+|\sin u-\sin v|\le$ $ 2|u-v|$ because each of the real functions $\cos,\sin$ is Lipschitz-continuous with Lipschitz constant $1.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Show that for any bounded sequence $(x_n)_n$ of complex numbers, the function $t\mapsto (e^{tx_n})_n$, $[0,1]\to \ell^\infty$ is continuous. Use this to show that your set is path connected.

**Hint 2**: Show that if $X$ is a metric space and $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions $X\to \mathbf C$ which are [equicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity), then $f(x)=(f_n(x))_n$ is a continuous function $X\to \ell^\infty$.

Comment: do you have to use equicontinuity? Because if there's a simpler way that'd be preferred.

Comment: For your second hint, I was thinking of taking $X = [0,1]$ under the standard metric and $f_n(t) = e^{tx_n}$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of complex numbers. Is that the right approach?

Comment: also, could you provide a hint as to how to show that the sequence $\{e^{tx_n}\}_n$ is an equicontinuous family of functions?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you *have to*, but it seems to be the most intuitive way for me. Yes, that is the point of the second hint. To show the equicontinuity, consider the derivatives (this allows you to show that the diagonal function is not only continuous, but actually continuously differentiable itself - but infinite dimensional differentiability is beyond the scope of your problem, I guess; anyway, continuity easily follows).